# How to have getElementbyId different than Null after page loaded

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am using Mustache to generate pages based on Data.

**My problem:** I need to getElementbyid in the page generated by Mustache. However, it always returns NULL. Do you have any ideas how I can fix it ? (I left a comment in main.js in the part where I am having issues.)

3 pages to reproduce my case:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="test-id">

<!-- Generated Content  -->

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/file-system/file-system.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`template_page.html` (where Mustache generate a page based on Data)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="template-div">

    <!-- part filled by Mustache -->

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/file-system/file-system.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript part

`main.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

// I get NULL but I want to find a way to get a None null value !!!
console.log(document.getElementById("test-get-id-value"));


// Data to get the different pages
var ALL_DATA = [
{
    'lastname': 'lastname_1',
    'firstname': 'firstname_1'
},
{
    'lastname': 'lastname_2',
    'firstname': 'firstname_2'
},
{
    'lastname': '"lastname_3"',
    'firstname': 'firstname_3'
}
];

// Function to get the different links
function displayData(obj_name) {

var theDiv = document.getElementById("test-id");

obj_name.forEach(doc => {
       var lastname = doc['lastname'];
       var firstname = doc['firstname'];

       newdiv = document.createElement("div")
       var text = document.createTextNode(lastname + ' ' + firstname);
       var anchor_value = document.createElement("a")
       url = lastname + firstname + '.html'
       anchor_value.setAttribute("href", "template_page.html" + "?firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname);
       anchor_value.setAttribute("class", "link-a");
       anchor_value.onclick = createPage();
       anchor_value.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Contact him"));
       newdiv.appendChild(text);
       newdiv.appendChild(anchor_value);
       theDiv.appendChild(newdiv);

    });
};

displayData(ALL_DATA);


// Function to create the PAGE based on the Data
function createPage() {

    // get url parameters
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var firstname_value = url.searchParams.get("firstname");
    var lastname_value = url.searchParams.get("lastname");

    // get the data needed
    data = {
    'lastname': lastname_value,
    'firstname': firstname_value
    };

    var template = 

    `
    <h1> Welcome, {{firstname}} </h1>
    <h2> Your last name: {{lastname}} </h2>
    <form id="test-get-id-value">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    </form>

    `

    var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
    $("#template-div").html(html);

};


});
```

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't wait for dynamic content added by other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener for `DOMContentLoaded` fires when you first load your page, and at that instant, no html has been rendered by `Mustache`

You can get the non-null value only after the template is rendered, so execute all your logic after render of the template:

```
var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
$("#template-div").html(html);
var el = document.getElementById("test-get-id-value");
// Now run the logic you need
```

Comment: perfect ! That's the solution I needed